# How can i get current hover element of Semantic UI popup

Tags: semantic-ui

i had this simple code

```
$('.ui.popup').popup({
    title   : 'Popup Title',
    content : 'Hello I am a popup'
 });
```

How can i get attributes of the current hover element. I had tried:

```
$('.ui.popup').popup({
    title   : this.getAttribute("class"),
    content : 'Hello I am a popup'
 });

$('.ui.popup').popup({
    title   : $(this).attr("class"),
    content : 'Hello I am a popup'
 });
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hovered element is passed as the first argument in a popup's event callbacks. If you want to change the content of the popup, you'll probably want to use the *onShow* event which is triggered before the popup shows.

```
$('.ui.popup').popup({
    title   : 'Popup Title',
    content : 'Hello I am a popup',
    onShow: function(hovered) {
        $(this).find('.header').html($(hovered).attr('class'));
    }
 });
```

Notice that, to change the title, I'm changing the element with the class *header* inside a popup. This is because the popup in your example looks something like this once it's created:

```
<div class="header">Popup Title</div>
<div class="content">Hello I am a popup</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with JQuery.

```
$('.ui.popup').each(function(index){
    $(this).popup({
        title   : $(this).attr("class"),
        content : 'Hello I am a popup'
    });
});
```